# iptables / LXD - Mangle iptable - Route outgoing distant port (to distant server port 21) via eth0

Tags: iptables, routing, lxd

To summarize the context, it's an lxd container that always connects as an OpenVpn client.

**{wan}** <-> **{192.168.x.x <-> iptables <-> lxd bridge host 10.0.3.1}** <-> **{lxd container 10.0.3.3 | openvpn <-> iptables}**

In the container there is

- eth0 (ip 10.0.3.3) which is the client interface on an lxd bridge
- tun0 which connects as a client to an OpenVpn server

The host lxd (10.0.3.1) forwards 10.0.3.3 traffic to the external network, iptables always accepts outgoing connections.

The host and the lxd client both have iptables.

I had already done routing on 10.0.3.3 but for incoming port (for example incoming http port to 10.0.3.3 and responses on eth0, not tun0).

So I have a "novpn" routing table with a fwmark number.

My problem now is that I'm trying to do the inverse. Outgoing requests going to port 21 on any remote server must go through eth0 ("novpn" table).

I followed several posts on stackoverflow and integrated this into the iptables of the 10.0.3.3 client. I feel like it's just:

```
ip rule add fwmark 66 novpn table
ip route add default via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0 novpn table

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 21 -j MARK --set-mark 66
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j MARK --set-mark 66
```

On iptables of 10.0.3.1, I have a rule that accepts forwards from already established and known connections. So bridge should follow and I don't think any other rules are necessary?

But it doesn't work, when I look at tcpdump on the host (10.0.3.1) I see that the packets are sent with the openvpn IP, not 10.0.3.3. There also seems to be a problem with the checksum of sent packets -> cksum 0x1983 (incorrect -> 0xe8ec).

Curiously, when I do tcpdump on the console of the lxd client (10.0.3.3), tcpdump does not display anything and there I no longer understand anything.

I wonder if lxd takes precedence (maybe something like the proxy devices, etc.) over iptables (and tcpdump??), but that seems very weird to me.

If it can be useful, I have a rule "ip rule add to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx table novpn". So any connection to this ip goes through eth0 and, this is indeed the case, there the request is correct in tcpdump.

Can anybody help me.

Comment: It fails because the routing stack chose the source IP address before iptables could set a mark to reroute: the source IP isn't changed. Normally there's an more elegant method for this: `ip rule add ... ipproto tcp dport 21 ...`. But as it's FTP and uses a data channel *not* on port 21, I expect that it will fail later when transfering files (or just listing a directory) so I won't make an answer. See this Q/A on UL SE where I use this method: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581419/routing-port-traffic-over-specific-interface .

Comment: Thank you @A.B, that answers my question, because it's mainly the technical problem that interests me, not necessarily a specific port / protocol. I didn't know about these new ip rules, it's much more logical and practical than using iptables.